# as.POSIXct.numeric error when executing ldply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a list "list.of.df" containing 3 data frames, that I coerce into a single data frame containing columns of all data frames using `ldply` from `plyr` package i.e.

```
df <- ldply(list.of.df)
```

This approach used to work, but today I have a new set of data and I received an error

> Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(what, tz = tzone) : 'origin' must be supplied

There are a few `POSIXct` variables in the 3 data frames, so it may be a bit meddlesome to manually troubleshoot everytime I have a new set of data. Instead, is there a way for me to pass the `origin` required in the `ldply` call?

The list can be `load`ed from the dropbox link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/92t99y5j0w0sdsc/listofdf.Rdata?dl=0).

Comment: When I try to `dget` your file, I get an error: `Error in parse(file = file, keep.source = keep.source) : invalid multibyte character in parser at line 3256`. Same when the text is opened in an editor.

Comment: That is strange. Have replaced with an Rdata file to be loaded instead. Thanks for the alert @Pascal .

Comment: You can replicate your problem with a much simpler example - e.g.: `list.of.df <- list(data.frame(a=Sys.time()),data.frame(a=1)); ldply(list.of.df)` - I suspect your issue comes down to mismatch of types of data (numeric / Date) between columns of the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the "BILLING SUBMISSION" column has dates in your first two list elements(which are dataframes), but has a numeric column in the last dataframe. ldply is trying to do an implicit conversion of the numeric value to a POSIX date value using the as.POSIX family of functions and to do that, an origin needs to be explicitly specified. See a solutions below:

1. Make sure all the datatypes in each dataframe you are trying to merge are the same or similar. You can achieve this with the code below using lapply to loop through your list:

   ```
   load(list.of.df)
   b <- lapply(list.of.df, function(x){
                     x[, "BILLING SUBMISSION"] <- as.POSIXct(x[, "BILLING SUBMISSION"], origin = "1970-01-01"); return(x)})
   df <- ldply(b)
   ```

You should probably change your column names to proper R column names just to be safe in the future. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ricky - this answer should be accepted - it is definitely the problem.

Comment: @thelatemail it definitely works, and I have upvoted it. I will be waiting for a while more before accepting as final answer to see if there is a more generalised approach that doesn't require me to identify the field name "BILLING SUBMISSION" . The data I get regularly changes (multiple Excel files over which I have no control, and which have a nasty habit of changing field names / contents), hence my initial thought of passing a param to ldply to sort things out on its own.

Comment: @Ricky - I doubt that's really possible without a tonne of extra checking code. Ultimately whatever process is generating the data should really be checking that each field is in the correct format.

Comment: @Ricky - I agree with thelatemail that you'll have to check the process generating the data and maybe post a question to get answers to solve that problem. Attempting to generalize the answer above will be impossible without knowing what will change in your data going forward. That is why it's answered directly to the question posed above.